# Changing form types on custom entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a custom entity with 4 different forms. The entity has a N:1 relationship with the contact entity. The contact lookup is viewable in each of the 4 forms.

I can go to a contact and add a new record for my custom entity. When the form launches, the contact is selected in the lookup field. If I switch to a different form, it loses the contact value in the lookup.

How can I prevent this from happening? After the second form loads and the contact is lost from the lookup, I can press F5 to refresh the page and the contact will then be displayed in the lookup. I could use a javascript to replicate this, but the best user experience is for that page to not have to be reloaded again. It should just load the form and the contact should automatically be selected.

Am I missing something? I find this very perplexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a save before changing the form, and on the onLoad of the new form, if you still don't get the value, you can force the values in the form to refresh

Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false);